# How to extract a html response and parse it JSON from a GET call in REST ASSURED framework?

Tags: json, rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

In Postman I have did in the below way and want to do the same in Rest Assured framework. I want to parse and save the "tltkt" value in  Rest Assured framework. How can I do that in Rest Assured?

GET call :https://prod.streaming/com/account/signin/

Postman tests:**
Load the HTML response to $

```
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text())
console.log($("title").text()); // get title

console.log($('script#app-config').text().trim());
let appConfig = JSON.parse($('script#app-config').text().trim());

console.log(appConfig.tltkt);
pm.collectionVariables.set("saved_tl_tkt", appConfig.tl_tkt);

console.log(pm.collectionVariables.get("saved_tl_tkt"), ":from pm");
```

**Response in HTML:**

```
main id="main-container"
script id="app-config" type="application/json"

{"tltkt":"QVdMcHpmWitoWENSSU8zN0FtYzNmWlJVdFFrQkoxOUVJTE5iOHQvTXZ" , "imageHost": https:\/\/prod-wwwimage-us.com, "regionBaseUrl:""};
```

Comment: My suggestion is getting Response as String then extract by regex.

Comment: I tried tthe below code in Rest Assured framework  String bodyTxt = response.htmlPath().getString("html.body.main.script") and it worked which gave the {{"tltkt":"QVdMcHpmWitoWENSSU8zN0FtYzNmWlJVdFFrQkoxOUVJTE5iOHQvTXZ" , "imageHost": https:\/\/prod-wwwimage-us.com, "regionBaseUrl:""} . But I am only looking for tltkt and its value. Please need inputs how can  get it with regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you've already had `{"tltkt":"QVdMcHpmWitoWENSSU8zN0FtYzNmWlJVdFFrQkoxOUVJTE5iOHQvTXZ" , "imageHost": https:\/\/prod-wwwimage-us.com, "regionBaseUrl:""}`

Because it's not valid json, so I use regex to extract value from this string.

```
String bodyTxt = ...;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"tltkt\":\"(.+?)\"");
Matcher matches = pattern.matcher(bodyTxt);
String tltkt = "";
if(matches.find()) {
    tltkt = matches.group(1);
}
System.out.println(tltkt);
//QVdMcHpmWitoWENSSU8zN0FtYzNmWlJVdFFrQkoxOUVJTE5iOHQvTXZ
```